# ¿Cómo usar la misma BD para web y mobil en Genexus?

Tags: sql, genexus, genexus15

Estoy haciendo un proyecto para android y ios pero necesito usar la misma Base de Datos para usarla en web panels, es decir, una BD para android, ios y web.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO, lecturas recomendada [tour], aprende como preguntar aca [ask].

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿Cómo está tu infraestructura actual? La base de datos debe ser independiente del front-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en las opciones de tu generador, puedes agregar uno nuevo, ahí es donde puedes incluir el generador web dentro de la misla kb para poder ocupar la misma bd